# AttachThreadInput returns 0 when passed processId (idAttachTo) of edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, msdn

```
static class Win32
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint AttachThreadInput(uint thread, uint attachToThread, bool attach);
            [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);
        }

private void MakeMeActive()
        {
            uint activeProcess = Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(Win32.GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            uint thisThread = Win32.GetCurrentThreadId();
            if ( activeProcess != 0 )
            {
                uint isSuccess = Win32.AttachThreadInput(thisThread, activeProcess, true);
                Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
                var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
                IntPtr hWnd = wih.Handle;
                Win32.BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
                Win32.AttachThreadInput(thisThread, activeProcess, false);
            }
        }
```

For above code,
`uint isSuccess = Win32.AttachThreadInput(thisThread, activeProcess, true);`

isSucess is false, which means that active thread and active processes are not attached. This is happening only when process is edge browser and working fine for chrome browser. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: From this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput), if either of the specified threads does not have a message queue, this method will fails, please try to set debugger to check the code. Besides, try to get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)(Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: There is no extended error information; do not call GetLastError. This behavior changed as of Windows Vista.).